# ggplot2 facet_wrap() 4 scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset (from R):

```
 head(anscombe)
  x1 x2 x3 x4   y1   y2    y3   y4
1 10 10 10  8 8.04 9.14  7.46 6.58
2  8  8  8  8 6.95 8.14  6.77 5.76
```

And now I would like to plot scatter plot of `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)`, `(x3,y3`) and  `(x4, y4)` in grid using `ggplot2`. Each subplot should also have title "1", "2","3","4" respectively. It should be similar as when we use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` I looked into `facet_wrap` documentation but the examples seems to be not covering this simple case. How can I achieve it in ggplot2?

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, please "accept", otherwise, perhaps you can edit your answer to expand on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible not all of this is required, but it worked for me. To see what it is doing, just iterate through, line-by-line, and look at the intermediate steps.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
mutate(df, i = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, val, -i) %>%
  mutate(pane = gsub("[a-z]", "", key),
         key = gsub("[^a-z]", "", key)) %>%
  spread(key, val) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~pane)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, if hard-coding the dataset numbers 1-4 is acceptable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(anscombe)

list(
  transmute(anscombe, x=x1, y=y1, dataset=1),
  transmute(anscombe, x=x2, y=y2, dataset=2),
  transmute(anscombe, x=x3, y=y3, dataset=3),
  transmute(anscombe, x=x4, y=y4, dataset=4)
) %>%
bind_rows() %>%
ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~ dataset)
```

The main thing is that you need all the x-coordinate values (x1 to x4) in one variable, and all y-coordinates (y1 to y4) in another.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

You could try without `facet_wrap` too:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(ggplot(df, aes(x1, y1))+geom_point(size=2),
             ggplot(df, aes(x2, y2))+geom_point(size=2),
             ggplot(df, aes(x3, y3))+geom_point(size=2),
             ggplot(df, aes(x4, y4))+geom_point(size=2))
```

[image]